How to continue scrolling parent widget when webview reaches its end - Flutter
So as it comes from the title, consider I have a scrollable widget in flutter web with different widgets inside of it. I want to freely scroll in web, but when I reach to the webview widget and my mouse is hovered on it, I am only able to scroll the webview content and when I reach at the bottom/top of the webview content, then I should be able to scroll down/up. But the actual thing happening here is that when I hover on webview, I am only able to scroll the webview content and not the parent widget.
So how can I scroll in parent widget when I reached at the top/bottom of webview content?
This is what I've done so far. As simple as implementing webview using HtmlElementView 
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'dart:html';

void main() {
  runApp(const MainApp());
}

class MainApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MainApp> createState() => _MainAppState();
}

class _MainAppState extends State<MainApp> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // ignore: undefined_prefixed_name
    ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory(
      'webview',
      (int viewId) => IFrameElement()
        ..src = 'https://flutter.dev'
        ..style.height = '100%'
        ..style.width = '100%',
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                height: 400,
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 400,
                child: HtmlElementView(
                  viewType: 'webview',
                  key: UniqueKey(),
                  creationParams: <String, dynamic>{
                    'url': 'https://flutter.dev',
                  },
                  onPlatformViewCreated: (int id) {
                    // The platform view has been created. You can now send messages to it.
                    // window.postMessage(id, 'Hello, world!');
                  },
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                height: 400,
                color: Colors.green,
              ),
              Container(
                height: 400,
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


Can you share what you've tried so far?

Just updated the question with sample code @NipulRathod

Try this code to continue scrolling parent widget.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class WebViewScrollExample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WebViewScrollExampleState createState() => _WebViewScrollExampleState();
}

class _WebViewScrollExampleState extends State<WebViewScrollExample> {
  final GlobalKey _webViewKey = GlobalKey();
  final ScrollController _parentScrollController = ScrollController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('WebView Scroll Example'),
      ),
      body: NotificationListener<ScrollEndNotification>(
        onNotification: (notification) {
          if (notification.metrics.atEdge &&
              notification.metrics.pixels == 0) {
            // WebView scrolled to the top
            _parentScrollController.animateTo(
              0,
              duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
              curve: Curves.ease,
            );
          } else if (notification.metrics.atEdge &&
              notification.metrics.pixels ==
                  notification.metrics.maxScrollExtent) {
            // WebView scrolled to the bottom
            _parentScrollController.animateTo(
              _parentScrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
              duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
              curve: Curves.ease,
            );
          }
          return true;
        },
        child: ListView(
          controller: _parentScrollController,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              height: 400, // Adjust height as needed
              child: WebView(
                key: _webViewKey,
                initialUrl: 'https://example.com',
                javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
              ),
            ),
            // Other widgets in the parent ListView
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


As I mentioned in the question I'm working on flutter web and webview widget does not support  flutter web
